# pass on multiple columns to function within dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out the syntax of working with dplyr and I'm running into problems on how to pass on more than a single column to another function (e.g. str_detect). I want to search through a tibble and select all rows there a certain string is detected. I can run this for a specific column (e.g. col3 in the example below), but would like to look through some and/or all columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

col1 <- c("plate_ABC", "text", "text", "text")
col2 <- c("text", "this is plate B", "text", "text")
col3 <- c("text", "text", "C-plate", "text")

df <- as_tibble(data_frame(col1, col2, col3))

df %>% filter(str_detect(col3, "plate"))
```

Output:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(col3, "plate"))

## A tibble: 1 x 3
#  col1  col2  col3   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1 text  text  C-plate
```

Desired Output:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(?SOME/ALL Cols?, "plate"))

## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  col1      col2            col3   
#  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  
#1 plate_ABC text            text   
#2 text      this is plate B text   
#3 text      text            C-plate
```

Comment: Is your expected solution should not use `filter` or `reduce`?  I am confused

Comment: No, sorry if I'm unclear. Any and all solutions are great. I'm very new to coding (only a couple of weeks in) so it takes me a while to understand the syntax and figure out the most convenient way to use the different commands. I think that in this case rowwise %>% filter is most intuitive for me to understand.

Comment: The `rowwise` should be slow compared to the vectorized option

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I think right now speed is not an issuse (datatables are very small), but I will keep this in mind as I become more familiar with coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = ~str_detect(., "plate"))))

#  col1      col2            col3   
#  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  
#1 plate_ABC text            text   
#2 text      this is plate B text   
#3 text      text            C-plate
```

Or rowwise :

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(str_detect(c_across(), 'plate')))
```

---

If you have older version of `dplyr` (<1.0.0) you can use `filter_all`/`filter_at` :

```
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., 'plate')))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak. So I think I understand the first: str_detect will evaluate across all columns trying to find plate. If any of these evaluations are T, then the line will be filtered. And rowwise means that each row is evaluated individually. That's gotta be useful in generating summary stats across columns as well.

I am struggling with the second solution since I'm having a hard time understanding the syntax and what exactly the period, tilde, ... indicate. I'll try and figure it out as I'm going along.

Comment: tilde(`~`) is used to apply formula style syntax. It is similar to anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, grepl, pattern = 'plate')),]
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  col1      col2            col3   
#  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  
#1 plate_ABC text            text   
#2 text      this is plate B text   
#3 text      text            C-plate
```

---

Or using `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(`dim<-`(grepl('plate', as.matrix(df)), dim(df))) > 0,]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(., 'plate')) %>% 
           reduce(`|`))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  col1      col2            col3   
#  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  
#1 plate_ABC text            text   
#2 text      this is plate B text   
#3 text      text            C-plate
```

#### Benchmarks

Timings on a slightly bigger dataset

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e6), ]
system.time(df1 %>% filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = ~str_detect(., "plate")))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.597   0.139   1.736 

system.time(df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(str_detect(c_across(), 'plate'))))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #178.694   1.477 180.864 

 system.time(df1 %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., 'plate'))) )
 # user  system elapsed 
 # 1.461   0.061   1.499 

 system.time(df1[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, grepl, pattern = 'plate')),])
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  2.792   0.025   2.778 

 system.time(df1 %>%
   filter(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(., 'plate')) %>% 
        reduce(`|`)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.471   0.054   1.505
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. For the 'tidyverse' solution the same comment applies as above (even though it's already easier to understand by using `reduce` as individual command rather than nesting it within filter. Lots to learn!